# firefox extension SQLite saving and getting

Tags: sqlite, firefox, save

Ok now for the juicy stuff. All attempts failed to save my string so far.

Here is the code for saving it in sqllite in firefox extension:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
                     .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
    file.append("my_db_file_name.sqlite");

    var storageService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/storage/service;1"]
                                   .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIStorageService);

    var mDBConn = storageService.openDatabase(file);

    mDBConn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_det (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, acc STRING)");
    mDBConn.execute("INSERT INTO log_det (acc) VALUES(" + window['gluistr']+ ")");
    mDBConn.drop();
```

And the code for retrieving the value:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
                     .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

file.append("my_db_file_name.sqlite");

var storageService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/storage/service;1"]
                                   .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIStorageService);

var mDBConn = storageService.openDatabase(file);

var res = mDBConn.execute("SELECT * FROM log_det");

mDBConn.drop();
```

Is not working. Anybody knows why? Is "execute" ok or do I need "createStatement" or "executeSimpleSQL". I am confused.

Comment: Ok. I commented out mDBConn.drop() and changed "execute" to "executeSimpleSQL" in the setting function and to "createStatement" in the getting function. Now I get the following message: [object StatementJSHelper]

Answer (score 3):

Use `executeSimpleSQL`.

`openDatabase` returns a [mozIStorageConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/MozIStorageConnection) instance, which does not have any method named `execute`. You can use [executeSimpleSQL](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/MozIStorageConnection#executeSimpleSQL.28.29) any time you want to execute a SQL statement without bound parameters (which is what you're doing).

You were probably thinking of [mozIStorageStatement's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageStatement) `execute` method. `executeSimpleSQL` is not sufficient when bound parameters are necessary. Instead, you need to create a statement, bind any parameters, and *then* execute it:

```
var statement = mDBConn.createStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM log_det WHERE column_name = :parameter");
statement.bindStringParameter(0, "value");
statement.execute();
statement.reset();
```

Also note that `mozIStorageConnection` does not have any method named `drop`. Maybe you meant to write `mDBConn.close()`?

All of this is covered here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/storage

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said and read the storage page but it is not working. Then I inserterd a row into the table with SQLlite Manager and tried to read it with the above statement. Isn't there an easier solution to save a simple string? I tried so far: localStorage, preferences, cookies, writing to a file and sqllite and nothing works.

Comment: @user366121 -- If all of those avenues are failing, then my guess is that it has nothing to do with your SQLite code and is probably something else altogether.